# Find the unique integer that appears m times in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

where all other integers in this array appeared `n` times. we have `n>m`.
all elements in this array are integers. Can you design an algorithm that works in `O(N)` where `N` is the number of elements in the array, while minimizing the space complexity? In the best case space complexity can be limited to `O(log(m))`.

a special case is `n=2` and `m=1` (which is easy). Is there a generalized algorithm that can handle arbitrary `m` and `n`?

thanks

Comment: At this moment the both published solutions with "hashtable" require: time O(N*log2(N/n)) and space O(N/n). Could you publish the solution if you find better one?

Comment: Additional question: are integer numbers in the table are sequential (like in this example [3,3,2,1,1] numbers are from 1 to 3)? For these type we can replace hashtable with simple reference array with zero cost instead log2(N/n).

Comment: No, not sequential but very random

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hashtable that maps numbers in the array to the number of occurrences.  You can iterate through the array, incrementing the number of occurrences for each number. Then, you can iterate through the hashtable, searching for a key with `n` occurrences.

Comment: But for hashtable search you need to add O(log N), so it would be O(N * log N)

Comment: If you have unlimited memory you can replace hashtable with a huge array size by M (max(all number))

Comment: Searching for an element in a hashtable is O(N), so the algorithm is O(2N), which is O(N).

Comment: Sorry but I meant to minimize space complexity. In the best case it could be O(1) space

Comment: If search in hashtable is O(N), then total time is O(N^2)

Comment: @agershun The search is only happening once, not one time per element, so its running time is added to the running time of the rest of the algorithm.

Comment: This is true, but the operation get or set hash[i] costs some O() and it performs for every element in the main loop, so they multiplicate. It can be reduce to zero, if you have direct indexation (case of huge array - but according the author it is not a case)

Comment: The operation to get or set hash[i] is O(1) because it is simply a matter of accessing an element of an array.

Answer (score 1):

If the array has length > m, then pivot on a random element in the array. Find the half of the array that has length m (mod n), and repeat on that half.

This has expected run-time O(N), and requires O(1) additional storage.

Comment: Interesting idea. Worst case would be worse than O(N), though, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

The below algo might be what you're looking for. Basically, you create a map with key as the integer value and the value as the number of occurrence.you loop through your array just once and anytime a numbers occurs more than once, you increase it's count

```
public static void findCount (int[] array,int m, int n){

    if(m>n){
       thrown new IllegalArgumentException("m is greater than n");
    }
    Map<Integer,Integer> intCount = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

       for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (!intCount.containsKey(array[i])) intCount.put(array[i], 0);
        intCount.put(array[i], intCount.get(array[i]) + 1);
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : words.entrySet()) {
          Integer key = entry.getKey();
          Integer value = entry.getValue();
           if(value==m){
          System.out.println("Value "+key+" Occurs "+value+" times");
     }            
   }
}
```

Comment: intCount.get(ind_words[i]) + 1) costs about O(log2 N)

Comment: It's "intCount.get(array[i]) + 1" and if what you're saying in right, then that's even better than O(n)

Comment: Do not forget about main cycle costs O(N), so the total is O(N*log2N).

Comment: You can use a hashtable and get() should be O(1) assuming there are no chaining which will result in a linkedlist in the buckets

Comment: May be I am so strict. According the question the size of hashtable would be about N/n, so the search time inside hash is log2(N/n), and the total is O(N*log2(N/n)). If n is relatively big, this 'hashtable' add-on would be unimportant.

Answer (score 0):

The case n=2, m=1 can be done by xoring all the numbers together in the array A.

This idea can be generalised by counting (modulo n) the number of elements in A with the i'th bit set. That count is non-zero if and only if the i'th bit of the answer is set.

This gives you an O(N.log(max(A))) way to compute the solution using O(log(n)) additional storage.

This doesn't achieve the O(log(N)) run-time and O(log(m)) storage complexities given in the question, but it seems an interesting approach.